# Finding Class type of a Tomcat thread to solve a memory leak

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks, threadpool, visualvm

There is an apache tomcat spring based web-application running that is serving an api and also running some threads. There has been a memory issue and the application stopped working.

I restarted the application with higher Xmx and Xms values. Enabled the JMX connection and hooked VisualVM.

The web application on a very high load should be serving maximum of 400 to 500 requests at a time. However, I see that there are thousands of threads hanging around in a WAIT state. Here is a picture:

[image: VisualVM analysing Threads]

The log file also shows the following thousands of lines:

```
    SEVERE: The web application [/TESTAPP] appears to have started a thread named [pool-11719-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
May 16, 2016 1:17:54 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/TESTAPP] appears to have started a thread named [pool-11720-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
May 16, 2016 1:17:54 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/TESTAPP] appears to have started a thread named [pool-11721-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
May 16, 2016 1:17:54 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/TESTAPP] appears to have started a thread named [pool-11722-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
May 16, 2016 1:17:54 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/TESTAPP] appears to have started a thread named [pool-11723-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
May 16, 2016 1:17:54 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/TESTAPP] appears to have started a thread named [pool-11724-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
May 16, 2016 1:17:54 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/TESTAPP] appears to have started a thread named [pool-11725-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

So, I recon if I find out the Class Name of the threads that are waiting, I may be able to dig in to it and see whats making the thread to remain in a wait state.

Is there a way to find out the thread name that is waiting?
Is there any other way to analyse this and solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Look for [`Executors.new..`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool%28%29) and similar. Something creates new pools all the time but doesn't call [`.shutdown()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown%28%29)

Comment: I searched the web app code, there is no sign of a 'shutdown' ... Thanks that could be it ...